# ESP32 не обменивается ключами по BLE

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, esp32, bluetooth-le

Железяка `ESP32-WROOM-32D`, framework-arduinoespressif32 == 3.20011.230801. Код на данный момент такой:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

typedef union Hwid
{
  byte data[16];

  struct
  {
    uint32_t chipId;
    byte mac[6];
    byte mac2[6];
  } esp8266;
  struct
  {
    uint32_t chipId;
    uint32_t pad;
    uint64_t efusemac;
  } esp32;
} Hwid;

Hwid get_id()
{
  Hwid boardid;
  boardid.esp32.efusemac = ESP.getEfuseMac();
  for (int i = 0; i < 17; i += 8)
  {
    boardid.esp32.chipId |= ((boardid.esp32.efusemac >> (40 - i)) & 0xff)
                            << i;
  }
  boardid.esp32.pad = boardid.esp32.chipId;
  return boardid;
}

#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
#include <BLE2902.h>

#include "BLEHIDDevice.h"
#include "HIDTypes.h"
#include "HIDKeyboardTypes.h"

#define SERVICE_UUID "9a8ca9ef-e43f-4157-9fee-c37a3d7dc12d"
#define BLINK_UUID "e94f85c8-7f57-4dbd-b8d3-2b56e107ed60"
#define SPEED_UUID "a8985fda-51aa-4f19-a777-71cf52abba1e"

#define DEVINFO_UUID (uint16_t)0x180a
#define DEVINFO_MANUFACTURER_UUID (uint16_t)0x2a29
#define DEVINFO_NAME_UUID (uint16_t)0x2a24
#define DEVINFO_SERIAL_UUID (uint16_t)0x2a25

#define BATTERY_UUID (uint16_t)0x180F
#define BATTERY_LEVEL_CHARACTERISTIC (uint16_t)0x2A19
#define BATTERY_LEVEL_DECRIPTOR (uint16_t)0x2901

#define DEVICE_MANUFACTURER "Eri"
#define DEVICE_NAME "Kalitka"

#define PIN_BUTTON 0
#define PIN_LED LED_BUILTIN

BLECharacteristic *battChar;

BLEHIDDevice *hid;
BLECharacteristic *input;
BLECharacteristic *output;

uint8_t batt_level = 67;

class MyCallbacks : public BLEServerCallbacks
{
  void onConnect(BLEServer *pServer)
  {

    pServer->startAdvertising();
  }

  void onDisconnect(BLEServer *pServer)
  {
  }
};
BLEServer *pServer;

void init_hid(String chipId)
{

  const uint8_t report[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

  hid = new BLEHIDDevice(pServer);
  input = hid->inputReport(1);   // <-- input REPORTID from report map
  output = hid->outputReport(1); // <-- output REPORTID from report map
  hid->manufacturer()->setValue(DEVICE_MANUFACTURER);
hid->manufacturer()->setAccessPermissions(ESP_GATT_PERM_READ_ENCRYPTED);
  hid->deviceInfo()->createCharacteristic(DEVINFO_NAME_UUID, BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ)->setValue(DEVICE_NAME);
  hid->deviceInfo()->createCharacteristic(DEVINFO_SERIAL_UUID, BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ)->setValue(chipId.c_str());

  hid->hidInfo(0x00, 0x01);

  hid->reportMap((uint8_t *)report, sizeof(report));

  battChar = hid->batteryService()->getCharacteristic(BATTERY_LEVEL_CHARACTERISTIC);
  battChar->setAccessPermissions(ESP_GATT_PERM_READ_ENCRYPTED);
  hid->startServices();
}

class MySecurity : public BLESecurityCallbacks
{

  uint32_t onPassKeyRequest()
  {
    Serial.printf("PassKeyRequest");
    return 434343;
  }
  void onPassKeyNotify(uint32_t pass_key)
  {
    Serial.printf("The passkey Notify number:%d", pass_key); //WORKS
  }
  bool onConfirmPIN(uint32_t pass_key)
  {
    Serial.printf("The passkey YES/NO number:%d", pass_key);
    return true;
  }
  bool onSecurityRequest()
  {
    Serial.printf("SecurityRequest");
    return true;
  }

  void onAuthenticationComplete(esp_ble_auth_cmpl_t cmpl)
  {
    Serial.printf("Starting BLE work!"); //WORKS
    if (cmpl.success)
    {
      Serial.printf("sucess");
      Serial.println(cmpl.key_present); // == 0
    }
  }
};

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Starting...");

  pinMode(PIN_BUTTON, INPUT);
  pinMode(PIN_LED, OUTPUT);

  String devName = DEVICE_NAME;
  String chipId = String(get_id().esp32.chipId, HEX);
  devName += '_';
  devName += chipId;

  BLEDevice::init(devName.c_str());
  BLEDevice::setEncryptionLevel(ESP_BLE_SEC_ENCRYPT);
  BLEDevice::setSecurityCallbacks(new MySecurity());
  pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();

  pServer->setCallbacks(new MyCallbacks());

  // devinfo(chipId);
  // battery();

  init_hid(chipId);

  // ----- Advertising

  BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = pServer->getAdvertising();

  pAdvertising->setAppearance(ESP_BLE_APPEARANCE_HID_GAMEPAD);
  pAdvertising->addServiceUUID(hid->hidService()->getUUID());
  pAdvertising->addServiceUUID(hid->batteryService()->getUUID());

  BLESecurity *pSecurity = new BLESecurity();
  pSecurity->setStaticPIN(434343);
  pSecurity->setAuthenticationMode(ESP_LE_AUTH_REQ_SC_BOND);

  pServer->startAdvertising();

  Serial.println("Ready");
  Serial.print("Device name: ");
  Serial.println(devName);
}

void printbond()
{

  int num = 0;
  esp_ble_bond_dev_t *dev_list;
  esp_ble_bond_dev_t dev;
  esp_bd_addr_t addr;
  esp_ble_get_bond_device_list(&num, dev_list);
  Serial.print("bonded: ");
  Serial.println(num);
  if (num == 0)
  {
    return;
  }
  num--;
  for (; num; num--)
  {
    dev = dev_list[num];
    String s((const uint8_t *)dev.bd_addr, (unsigned int)ESP_BD_ADDR_LEN);
    Serial.println(s);
    String k((const uint8_t *)dev.bond_key.pcsrk_key.csrk, (unsigned int)ESP_BT_OCTET16_LEN);
    Serial.println(k);
  }
}

void loop()
{

  printbond();

  delay(1000);
  if (pServer->getConnectedCount() > 0)
  {

    hid->setBatteryLevel(batt_level);
  }
  batt_level++;
  batt_level %= 101;

  // Serial.printf("%d\t", batt_level);
  Serial.println(pServer->getConnectedCount());
}
```

Пинкод запрашивает с андроида, но не передает ключи. С компьютера пинкод не запрашивается. BOND не добавляется на ESP.

esp_ble_get_bond_device_list(&num, dev_list); выдает ноль.

cmpl.key_present выдает ноль

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: https://github.com/nkolban/esp32-snippets/issues/556